# How do I fix this AWS Error while connecting AWS EC2 Server and AWS S3 Storage Files (InvalidAccessKeyId)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, server, amazon-iam

I am using the windows command prompt with the AWS Command Line Interface to connect the AWS S3 storage files and EC2 Server, I typed the following info (Part 1) and got an error (Part 2).

Part 1

AWS Access Key ID: (I put the EC2 Key pair name)
AWS Secret Access Key ID: (I put the key pair)
Default region name: us-east-2
Default output format: All (according to EC2 Security > Outbound Rules > Protocol)

Part 2

C:\Users(username)>aws s3 ls s3://www.(domain name)

An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Comment: The [AWS Access key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html) is a separate concept from an EC2 SSH key, for example for an IAM user or IAM role.

Comment: Please don't share text as screenshots.  Simply copy the text and paste *as text*.  Do this and I will be able to read it and will explain

Comment: @erik258 I changed the image to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AWS Access Key ID: (I put the EC2 Key pair name)
> AWS Secret Access Key ID: (I put the key pair)

As @Anon Coward says, Ec2 Key pair is totally separate from AWS API access key / secret.

Go to IAM for your IAM user and generate a new IAM Access Key then rerun `aws configure` and paste in the values it gives you.  The access key will look like `AKIA.....` and the secret will be a bunch of random looking characters.